# Why am I receiving Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect)?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have been receiving 
**Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect)**
I have tried different solutions found on Stack Overflow but I am unable to fix it!
I have tried to use the `render_to_response`, and when I do that I receive this error:

**This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.
  "A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context "**

This is the forms.py

```
from django import forms


class AskForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Write your name here',
                'class': 'ask-page-input',
                'label': 'Student Name',
            }
        ))
    email = forms.EmailField(
        max_length=254,
        widget=forms.EmailInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Write your Email here',
                'class': 'ask-page-input',
                'label': 'Email',
            }
        ))
    subject = forms.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Write your Question or Related Subject here',
                'class': 'ask-page-input',
                'label': 'Subject',
            }
        ))

    message = forms.CharField(
        max_length=2000,
        widget=forms.Textarea(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Write your message here',
                'class': 'ask-page-input',
                'label': 'Message',
            }
        ))

    source = forms.CharField(  # A hidden input for internal use
        max_length=50,  # tell from which page the user sent the message
        widget=forms.HiddenInput()
    )

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ContactFrom, self).clean()
        name = cleaned_data.get('name')
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')
        subject = cleaned_data.get('subject')
        message = cleaned_data.get('message')
        if not name and not email and not subject and not message:
            raise forms.ValidationError('You have to write something!')
```

This is the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, render_to_response
from forms import AskForm

def askpage_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pass  # does nothing, just trigger the validation
    else:
        form = AskForm()
    return render(request, "ask.html",  {'form': form,  })
```

This is the html file

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Physics Quizzes Ask</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit" name="button">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: do you try with clearing cache?

Comment: Yes, I have tried doing that but it didn't work! @ShafikurRahman

Comment: Is it availbale 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in settings.py

Comment: Yes, it is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `form.py`
Change this

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()
```

To

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(AskForm, self).clean()
```

My Forms shows like this:
[image]

Comment: The form is not showing in the template and only the html button is.

Comment: do u render ask.html?

Comment: Yes, on the browser, I type _http://127.0.0.1:8000/ask/_ and get nothing but the submit button.

Comment: I test the code and my output added to my answer. Do u see any error?

Comment: I see nothing, the form itself is not showing up, only the submit button shows up and when I click it, it says _CSRF verification failed. Request aborted._

Comment: Maybe you are not loading ask.html please recheck your urls.py and which template actually rendered.

Comment: I don't understand why? Everything is the same, 
This is the urls.py
`from ask.views import ask_views as ask_function`
`    path('ask/', ask_function, name = 'website_ask_page')`

And this is the views.py
`def ask_views(request, *args, **kwargs):`
   ` return render_to_response('ask.html')`

Comment: Everything is the same and everything makes sense but it is not working, this is the error:

`This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.`
`  "A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context "`

I have used a RequestContext, but nothing.

Comment: Try to debug please